# How to structure database for Tinder functionality

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

I'm building a functionality similar to Tinder. People can 'like' or 'skip' photo's of someone else, if both people 'like' each other then there is a match.

What is the best approach of a database structure for this functionality? I want to be able to get a list of all matches and all matches per Person.

**Approach 1:**

```
Person | JudgedPerson | Like
------ | ------------ | ----
1      | 2            | yes
2      | 1            | yes
1      | 3            | yes
3      | 1            | no
2      | 3            | yes
```

This looks like a logical approach, but it is difficult to create a MySql query to discover matches. Or is there a simple way to discover it?

**Approach 2**

```
Person1 | Person2 | P1LikesP2 | P2LikesP1
------- | ------- | --------- | ---------
1       | 2       | yes       | yes
1       | 3       | yes       | no
2       | 3       | yes       | null
```

It's easy to create queries to get matches, but the datamodel might be not the best.

What is the best approach?
If approach 1 is the best approach, what mysql queries can I use to discover the matches?

Comment: With the first table you can easily make the second one: `select v.person1, v.judgedperson as person2, v.like as p1likesp2, lj.like as p2likesp1 FROM votes v LEFT JOIN votes lj ON ( v.judgedperson = lj.person1 and lj.judgedperson = v.person1) WHERE v.person1 = 1 and v.judgedperson = 2`

Comment: I think neither approach would scale to Tinder levels.  For a small system, a join table makes sense.  But after there are 10s of millions of users, you have a subset of the square of that and your join table will balloon and performance will tank.   Instead, each user should have two lists of "liked" IDs.  One list for those who "like" them back, and the second list for those that haven't yet.  (Plus some way of handling being "un-liked" or blocked.)

Comment: Then the "like" process first checks the other (the liked) user and sees if this user is already in the other user's liked list, if so, both users' lists get updated.  Otherwise just add to this users "liked-but-not-yet-liked-back" list.  So you need to perform two lookups, but the index grows linearly with the number of users, rather than quadratically and at Tinder-scale, that will make a world of difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a formal reason for why I prefer the first option, but it is clear that the second option is not completely normalized.

To query the first table and find pairs of people who like each other, you can try the following self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(t1.Person, t1.JudgedPerson) AS Person1,
                GREATEST(t1.Person, t1.JudgedPerson) AS Person2
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.JudgedPerson = t2.Person AND
       t1.Person       = t2.JudgedPerson
WHERE t1.Like = 'yes' AND
      t2.Like = 'yes'
```

Note: I added `DISTINCT` along with `LEAST`/`GREATEST` to the `SELECT` clause because each match will actually come in the form of a duplicate.  The reason for this is that, e.g. `1 -> 2, 2 -> 1` would be one matching record, but also `2 -> 1, 1 -> 2` would also be a second record.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would consider adding another option to the presented ones: having 2 tables - likes and matches:

**Matches**

```
 Person1 | Person2 
 ------  | --------
 1       | 2       
 1       | 3       
 2       | 1
 3       | 1
```

**Likes**

```
Who | Whom | Likes
--- | -----|---------
2   | 3    | 'no'
```

Getting matches would be a simple query:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Persons p
INNER JOIN Matches m ON p.Id = m.Person2
WHERE m.Person1 = @judgedPersonId
```

The idea is to precompute matches instead of resolving them on each query (either in background process or during Like operation - to remove two-way likes and add records to matches tables).

This way one gets faster and easier queries when selecting matches, but the approach involves additional complexity computing "matches" and doing related queries (e.g. finding people who are not yet matched and not disliked).

Comment: I actually don't get it. How is it documented if people don't like each other?

Comment: @klaasjansen Do you actually need to store dislikes ? (e.g. not to show persons profile anymore; but I'm pretty sure Tinder and such rotate profiles even when dislike happened) If you do, you might want to add additional column to Likes table; the main idea, however, was to separate likes/dislikes and actual matches.

Comment: Aaah.. Yes I also want to store dislikes. To make sure I'm not showing the same profile again (don't want that in my case, it's actually a little bit different from Tinder)

Comment: @klaasjansen updated the answer to reflect this.